# How can I correctly combine these two functions

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I am attempting a formula which outputs data from within a range depending on the matching criteria. So for example, if the columns Food category is Taco it then pulls from a list of ID numbers that correspond with a taco. I have a working formula

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(IMGID!C:C,MATCH(C5,IMGID!A:A,0)))
```

the issue is it only outputs the first ID from the respective range, so I thought I could include a formula that randomly pulls a cell from within a matching range. This formula

```
randbetween(1,counta(IMGID!C:C)
```

I believed I could simply combine the two and replace *IMGID!C:C* which is where the output or range comes from with

```
randbetween(1,counta(IMGID!C:C)
```

for this formula

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(randbetween(1,counta(IMGID!C:C),MATCH(C5,IMGID!A:A,0)))
```

but it doesn't work. It only displays an empty cell and I am at a lost

I have tried this formula

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(randbetween(1,counta(IMGID!C:C),MATCH(C5,IMGID!A:A,0)))
```

which is a combination of

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(IMGID!C:C,MATCH(C5,IMGID!A:A,0)))&randbetween(1,counta(IMGID!C:C)
```

---

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(IMGID!C:C,MATCH(C5,IMGID!A:A,0)))*randbetween(1,counta(IMGID!C:C)
```

There are no error messages only an empty cell where the formula is placed when using

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(randbetween(1,counta(IMGID!C:C),MATCH(C5,IMGID!A:A,0)))
```

On the other hand,

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(IMGID!C:C,MATCH(C5,IMGID!A:A,0)))
```

works but it only outputs the first option from within that range...I need variation and would like to output randomization of options from the list of possibilities within a range. This is the random formula

```
randbetween(1,counta(IMGID!C:C)
```

which works fine and I assumed I could just paste it into the earlier formula

Comment: Here is the link to the document with edit access for all users as well https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16lpkGtSubdWlt-MOp4eYbaWYl5-y9rcpw5onKO01LVI/edit#gid=0 @player0

Answer (score 0):

delete **B2:C** in **Missing_Photo** sheet and paste this in **B2**:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C2:C, IMGID!A2:C, 3, 0)))
```

and this in **C2**:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A, Storefront!B2:C, 2, 0)))
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately it still only outputs the very first Image ID from the respective range. For example, if the category is Pizza then the list of possibilities are 2222,3333,4444,5555. If 2222 is the first option in that range it always puts 2222. I would like it to randomly pick an ID number within the food category range. The reason for this is I use a tool which makes bulk changes to thousands of accounts and one of the options is to upload photos from a stock library of different food categories. Each photo has a corresponding ID number and it will upload the exact same photo to every store